# Magento 2 - multi database - multi websites

Tags: magento2, multidomain, multi-website

Is it possible to configure a single installation of Magento 2 with different websites and different domains on different databases?

eg.:

- www.domain.com - magento 2 installation on database1 - website1
- www.domain2.com on database2 - website2
- www.domain3.com on database3 - website3

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple domain with multiple websites in a single Magento 2 installation but you can't have multiple databases.

Magento 2 EE you can [split database](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html) but not for websites.

For your scenario maybe it makes sense to set up 3 differents magento installations.